# How to add new row at bottom of Kendo Grid (Vue.JS)?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-vue

I am using Kendo Grid Wrapper for Vue.JS and i need to add new row at bottom of Kendo Grid.

Kendo UI Grid for jQuery provides editable.createAt

"editable": {
    "createAt": "bottom"
}

How the above code can be used in vue.js wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .Editable(editable => { editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false); editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom); })
```

> In ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the version: 2019.2.621.I have reported this as a bug, refer link [add-new-row-at-bottom-of-kendo-grid-vue-js](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/1422200-add-new-row-at-bottom-of-kendo-grid-vue-js) for details